# Does logarithmic differentiation limit us to finding the derivative of positive x values only? How does that differ to taking absolutevalue logarithms

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Since the domain of a logarithmic function is only positive numbers, if you take the logarithm of both sides then take the derivative of both sides ( logarithmic differentiation) wouldn't that limit the derivative function's domain to only positive numbers?

2nd question, does the absolute value logarithm also limit the domain of the derivative function? By absolute value logarithm I mean something like **Ln |x|**

Comment: Your title should not be the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when talking about taking the log derivative of a function, what we really mean is $(1/f)df/dx$. While $(1/f)df/dx = d(\ln f)/dx$ is true for positive functions $f$, it's also true that for negative functions $f$, $(1/f)df/dx = d[\ln(- f)]/dx$. So as long as $f$ is never zero, we can say $(1/f)df/dx = d(\ln |f|)/dx$. On the other hand, if $f$ *is* zero anywhere, the log derivative becomes ill-defined. Best not to use it on such functions.

As for $(1/f)df/dx = d(\ln|f|)/dx$ itself, there is no restriction on its sign. It can be positive, negative, or zero. For a simple example, the function $e^{kx}$ is never zero for any real $k$, and $(1/e^{kx})d(e^{kx})/dx = k$. So the log derivative can be any real number.